# In VS2010, how to get VB.NET enum values to autocomplete without typing the enum type first?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, enums, autocomplete, intellisense

In VS2008, you could write, for instance,

```
dim enumValue as MyEnum
enumValue =
```

.. and then as soon as you typed the `=`, you'd get a list of possible values of `MyEnum`.

With VS2010, you have to type

```
dim enumValue as MyEnum
enumValue = MyEnum.
```

... before getting the list on typing the final `.`

This makes for a lot more typing and seems to be a retrograde step ... is there an option I'm missing? (I have 'Auto List members checked in the Text Editor options under 'Basic').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're not the first to be annoyed by this.  This looks to be likely to get fixed in SP1 according to this [feedback item](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551699/intellisense-enum-values).

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping I was just missing something obvious, but I guess not.  I hadn't noticed that the All/Common switch is a partial workaround, since its value is at least remembered.  However, I use 'All' almost all the time, so it's not that much use. Roll on SP1...